# Passing a List of data from serial communication between some Java classes asynchronously

Tags: java, serial-port

I'd like to develop an application with JSerialComm and JavaFX. I use async delimiter-mode data receiving mode in JSeialComm:

```
class MessageListener implements SerialPortMessageListener {

    private List<Byte> list;

    public List<Byte> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public MessageListener() {
        list = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    }

    public void addToList(Byte number) {
        list.add(number);
    }
    
    public void flushList()
    {
        list.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() {
        return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getMessageDelimiter() {
        return new byte[] { (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x0A };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delimiterIndicatesEndOfMessage() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        byte[] delimitedMessage = event.getReceivedData();

        for (byte b : delimitedMessage) {
            addToList(b);
        }

    }
}
```

The total functionality is OK. I open the port in my Main class and send data to the serial receiver. (Actually, the Main class itself is not important here but could be found in the link below.)

Since data receiving is performed asynchronously, data is received in MessageListener class and temporarily stored in *list* variable. I am searching for a way to inform the Main class about any new data so that it can update the GUI and do some businesses on them. On way may be constant polling for new data but it is not efficient.

The whole project is accessible [**here**](https://github.com/ImanHz/java-arduino-serial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [LinkedBlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) or any other class that implements [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). They have a `take()` method that blocks until the queue has an element available. As elements become available the `take()` method unblocks, and allows the processing code to execute.

I did something similar when I was waiting on serial data as I wanted to queue it for processing and process it sequentially.

In your listener class you would put elements into the queue:

```
class MessageListener implements SerialPortMessageListener {

    private LinkedBlockingDeque list;

    public LinkedBlockingDeque getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public MessageListener() {
        list = new LinkedBlockingDeque();

    }

    public void addToList(Byte number) {
        list.put(number);
    }
...
```

Then make a thread passing in both your parent StackPane or whatever GUI object you need to change and a reference to the queue and run a loop that waits for the queue to have bytes in it. You could also do this from the main class if you don't care if it gets blocked, but I usually try to avoid blocking `main()` if possible.

```
public class QueueProcessor extends Thread
{
    LinkedBlockingDeque queue = null;
    StackPane root = null;
    public QueueProcessor(StackPane tmpRoot, LinkedBlockingDeque tmpQueue)
    {
        root = tmpRoot;
        queue = tmpQueue;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //this will block until the queue has elements
            Byte b = (Byte)(queue.take());
            //processing code here
        }
    }
}
```

When you take from the queue, you are actually removing the object from the queue (i.e. no `clear()` method is needed). Java takes care of executing the processing code once the queue has bytes “for the taking”. If the queue is empty then the thread is resting.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.